# What is block level design in context of mobile application?

Tags: design, terminology, mobile

I was wondering if anyone can give me some direction related to "Block level design" in context of mobile application? Recently I saw a video in my university and a professional mentioned about building block level design of applications, since then it has stuck in my brain!

It would be really helpful if someone can share their knowledge.

Comment: it seems related to HTML : http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm , was it in an "HTML context" ? did you google it ?

Comment: Yes I did, But I want something related to mobile application development context. but no information at all on google :(

Comment: was it mobile native application or mobile web application ?

Comment: _professional mentioned about building block_ hm in MIDP mobile API, [media package](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/media/package-summary.html) is described as such in javadoc: _The MIDP 2.0 Media API is a directly compatible **building block** of the Mobile Media API (JSR-135) specification..._

Comment: I don't think there's a generally accepted definition of "block level design". You'd likely have to get clarification from the person using the term.  In the context of HTML "block level" could mean HTML elements that are not inline elements, and "block level design" could mean something dealing with these types of elements.  In a storage context, "block level design" could mean a design that stores data in blocks (like sectors). Etc.  Do you have more context about what the person was talking about in this video?

Answer (score 1):

A block level design is something which presents all the functional parts of your application in a visual format.
     In case of Block level diagram of Android application you can start with android architecture

[image: android system architecture]

and then from the applications block onwards you can have your application, then as per the responsibilities make separate blocks for related activities along with their respective UI wherever applicable (UI is not needed in case of services, broadcast receiver etc) in xml file. And your block diagram is ready.

Same process you can follow for your required mobile platform.

Note that the block diagram gives overall view of application. so no need to have detail description of every aspect.